# ActivityNotFoundException for an activity declared in my AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

I have a launched android application that works fine most of the time.  However 1 in about 1000+ runs I get an android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class exception.  The activity is declared in my manifest and I've never seen it crash myself. It is declared like this...

```
<activity android:name="com.myCompany.myPackage.MyDialog"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</activity>
```

The crash reports show it failing on all OS's from 1.5 to 2.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

--Gary

Comment: <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">

and my target is 4 which is believe is 1.6

Comment: What's the code to start the activity?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem, except it's 100% of the time.

Comment: I found that it only affects the activity I'm using as the launcher activity. So to solve it, I just extended the activity without changing anything in it, and declared the extended version of it in my manifest.

Answer (score 2):

an android.content.ActivityNotFoundException

be sure your `<activity` is inside your `<application` node =)

Comment: yep, it definitely is.  The only other thing that I can think of that is of note is my main activity has android:launchMode="singleTask".

Answer (score 0):

you don´t need to define all your package in your activity, you will define it in your manifest xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.myCompany.myPackage"
```

and then in your activity

```
<activity android:name=".MyDialog"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</activity>
```

Comment: Ah but i have multiple packages and this dialog is not in the default one.