# ActivityNotFoundException (YES, this activity is declared in AndroidManifest.xml)

Tags: android, android-manifest, preferenceactivity, library-project

I found a few threads reporting a similar problem but [none of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180459/activitynotfoundexception-for-an-activity-declared-in-my-androidmanifest-xml) really offers something that I haven't tried already.

An innocent such call:

```
mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(mActivity, MyEditPreferences.class));
```

with the following in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <application>
    <activity android:name="MyActivityLib" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.baseapp.MyEditPreferences" android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
 </application>
```

Triggers the following exception:

```
06-14 14:06:50.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9272): 
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
{com.example.baseapp.paypal/com.example.baseapp.MyEditPreferences};
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

The things is, this code used to work flawlessly before I changed it from a monolithic application project to a 2-part project that is comprised from a Library Project and an Application Project.

The AndroidManifest.xml is the one in the **library** project.

What do I need to do eliminate this `ActivityNotFoundException`?

Comment: Whats com.example.baseapp.paypal?? Are you using some paypal library?

Comment: @Ravi Vyas Yes, I am. This is the main reason I broke the monolithic application project to a 2-part project: library that is common to all Android markets and a tiny application project (with activity class derived from library activity class) that is customized to each Android market or appstore. Did you notice something?

Comment: I do not believe you can create an intent to call a class like that that is in a different package.

Comment: apart from your awesome rep score of 404 I cant seem to find anything with the information given :-(

Comment: @Maximus Why? I managed so far to solve all problems that stemmed  from breaking the monolithic application project to a 2-part project. Sometimes it involved ugly workarounds like [duplicating all assets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346889/how-to-reference-an-asset-in-a-library-project/6347111#6347111) but it works at least. If you could explain why, I may be able to come up with a workaround. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just solved the problem.

All I had to do was add the FQN to the **Application** project's `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.baseapp.MyEditPreferences"
          android:label="com.example.baseapp.MyActivityLib:string/app_name">
</activity>
```

In fact, I removed any reference to `MyEditPreferences` in the **Library** project's `AndroidManifest.xml` completely and it still works.

It also works with the original startActivity 1-line statement:

```
mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(mActivity, MyEditPreferences.class));
```

Conclusion: It's the application's `AndroidManifest.xml` that matters, not the library's.

Comment: here it is written: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: "In the manifest file of the application project, you must add declarations of all components that the application will use that are imported from a library project."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work?

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent();
mIntent.setClassName(mActivity, "com.example.baseapp.MyEditPreferences");
mActivity.startActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the suggestion. I just tried it and it didn't help. I also found a thread describing an incredibly similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363548/activitynotfound-exception-thrown-for-a-preferenceactivity-listed-in-the-manifest/5363603#5363603 The FQN approach worked him, but didn't solve the problem for me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you use classes which names are included in an android package (Settings, Preferences, Activity, ...), you will need to put this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, <name_of_your_package>.classname.class);
```

If you don't put "name_of_your_package", the compiler will think that you are refering to the class in android package (android.*).

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a very old thread, but I've just had the same problem. In my case all I had to do was to delete a spurious

```
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;
```

Answer (score -2):

Just check your manifest for errors that your IDE not pointed.